# How to overload << operator in inherited class in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, cout

My current code is not working.
I am trying to use << operator of `Person` class in the << operator of `Student` class. Is that possible?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person
{   
private:
int EGN;
public:
Person(int e):EGN(e){}
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Person& p);
};
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Person& p)
{
    out<<p.EGN<<endl;
    return out; 
}

class Student: public Person
{   
    private:
    int fn;
    public:

Student(int e, int f):Person(e)
{

    fn=f;

}
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Student& p);
};

 ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Student& p)
{
    Person :: operator << (out,p);
    out<<p.fn<<endl;
    return out; 
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Person's operator << is a friend, not a member, so you can't access it using the :: operator.

Try casting your student to a person to call the right overload:

```
out << static_cast<const Person &>(p);
```